# Move service to another partition

Tags: partition, raspberry-pi, services, dnsmasq

(I am using a Raspberry Pi 3b+)

I have the config of the service "dnsmasq" on my /etc-partition. /etc is read-only-mounted, so I need to mount it everytime so the service actually runs (by typing *sudo service dnsmasq start*).

My /data-partition would be writable - can I somehow move the whole service to /data? Is it enough to move the config-file to /data?

Comment: The default configuration file is`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. Read the [manual page](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) to find out how a non-default file can be specified. But that's not all; there are plenty of other relevant files like `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/resolv.conf` and so on. Whether you need alternative locations for them, I can't say. `dnsmasq` seems to have options that relocate most of them.

Comment: @berndbausch Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested: I changed the partition to writable - made everything a lot easier.